# Spotted a moving star-like object

Tags: star

So a couple days ago, my husband and I spotted a moving object in the sky just like a star. I know it wasn't a plane or a drone, and it was way up in the sky just a star. It just moved smoothly across the skies and than disappeared. I love to observe the sky so that was priceless for me and my husband.

Comment: I think it was probably an airplane, with its navigation lights turned on. It may have been an atypical meteor, too (the typical meteor moves quickly, it is visible only for some seconds, it makes a stripe, and it moves always linear), but I think a plane is the most probable.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description, that might be the [International Space Station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station#Sightings_from_Earth):

> The ISS is visible to the naked eye as a slow-moving, bright white dot because of reflected sunlight, and can be seen in the hours after sunset and before sunrise, when the station remains sunlit but the ground and sky are dark.

So if what you saw was not long after sunset, and if the object was quite bright and moving slowly across the sky, that might be the answer.

If you want to check for yourself, you can input your location on [this webpage](http://www.heavens-above.com/PassSummary.aspx?satid=25544) and change the search period to see if the ISS passed above your heads on that day.

Other possibilities include other satellites (not very bright but also moving smoothly in the sky), or—more rarely—particularly large shooting stars.